# Generate a RSA Private/Public Key pair for SSH login on Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, ssh, key-pair

I am working on a project where I need my app to generate a public/private RSA key for SSH login.

I have the following code so far to get the keys:

```
private void createKeyTest()
    {
        try
        {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
            byte[] pri = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
            byte[] pub = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

            String privateKey = new String(pri);
            String publicKey = new String(pub);

            Log.d("SSHKeyManager", "Private Key: " + privateKey);
            Log.d("SSHLeyManager", "Public Key: " + publicKey);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex)
        {
            Log.e("SSHKeyManager", ex.toString());
        }
```

When I print this out in Logcat I get random non textual characters when I am expecting the key to look something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEoQIBAAKCAQEAm8QDThbuEjAbQxbsdDltL2xdFkQOep3L0wseSJAxmDuvH6yB
9I2fEEmF+dcVoNo2DGCDZMw7EgdFsfQZNF+PzKdZwtvSUTDW/TmMHWux2wYimNU3
jhQ3kfxGmiLgMJHQHWLkESwd06rCr7s1yOnPObdPjTybt7Odbp9bu+E59U10Ri3W
JFxIhi9uYQvpRn4LT/VIfH/KBdglpbD9xBAneVbKFXW7....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Have you considered that you are correctly getting the string contained within the `---  ---` section?

Comment: `new String()` on some byte array will not give you base-64 encoding of the bytes (or whatever encoding is used for those RSA files).

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that, I've tried base 64 encoding it, but the string always looks far shorter than when it is generated using the linux command ssh-keygen -t rsa on a linux box

Comment: @Boardy - any solution for this meanwhile ?

Answer (score 5):

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

You can change

```
String privateKey = Base64.encodeToString(pri, Base64.DEFAULT);
String publicKey = Base64.encodeToString(pub, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

That will let you have Base64 version of public key and private key.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

These format called PEM , you can custom add it or use library "bouncycastle".

Here is bouncycastle example:[Export RSA public key to PEM String using java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130378/3935745)